# Rails 3 - HAML Block Passed to Partial Rendered in Original Context instead of Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, haml, partial

I have a partial that renders a table that I want to reuse on various pages.  Some of the views using it need to insert additional columns, so I created helper methods for adding and retrieving new column headers and code for generating the <TD>s based on the data for the current row.

The helpers look like this:

```
def table_column table_name, column_name, &block
  raise "block required" unless block_given?
  @@tables ||= {}
  table = @@tables[table_name]
  if table.nil?
    @@tables[table_name] = table = []
  end
  index = table.size
  table[index] = [column_name, block]
end

def table_cells table_name
  table = @@tables[table_name] || []
  table.map { |column| column[0] }
end

def table_headers table_name
  table = @@tables[table_name] || []
  table.map { |column| column[1] }
end
```

The partial uses the helpers to specify column details before rendering the table:

```
- table_column "tasks", "Name" do |task|
  %td= task.name

- table_column "tasks", "Start" do |task|
  %td= task.start_time.strftime(time_format)

- table_column "tasks", "End" do |task|
  %td= task.end_time.strftime(time_format)

%table
  %thead
    %tr
      - table_headers("tasks").each do |header|
        %th= header
  %tbody
    - @tasks.each do |task|
      %tr
        - table_cells("tasks").each do |cell|
          - cell.call(task)
```

This works fine.  I then have a view that adds a column before rendering the partial:

```
- table_column "tasks", "ID" do |task|
  %td=task.id

= render "table"
```

The **task** variable from the partial gets used when rendering the ID column, but for some reason the ID cells get rendered *above* the table!  The resulting HTML is similar to this:

```
<td>10001</td>
<td>10002</td>
<td>10003</td>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>End</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Steal underpants</td>
      <td>Feb.12, 2012</td>
      <td>Jun.07, 2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>???</td>
      <td>Jun.08, 2012</td>
      <td>Nov.13, 2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Profit!</td>
      <td>Nov.14, 2012</td>
      <td>Jan.23, 2013</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's as if the HAML renderer is remembering the original context of the block passed to **table_column**, but only when passed from outside the partial.  As a test, I moved the ID column code into the partial, and it works in that case.  I've also tried, passing strings instead of blocks to **table_column** (works), but I'd really prefer to pass a block of HAML since the code I need to use in the end will be much more complicated.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HAML is immediately rendering the call to table_column instead of simply adding the block to @@tables. I believe it is doing this because when you are calling the block from the partial, it is being rendered in the context of the view where you defined the block and not the partial itself. A better approach may be to conditionally have the partial add columns depending on the locals that you pass to it:

```
- if defined?(id) && id
  - table_column "tasks", "ID" do |task|
    %td=task.id

- table_column "tasks", "Name" do |task|
  %td= task.name

- table_column "tasks", "Start" do |task|
  %td= task.start_time.strftime(time_format)

- table_column "tasks", "End" do |task|
  %td= task.end_time.strftime(time_format)

%table
  %thead
    %tr
      - table_headers("tasks").each do |header|
        %th= header
  %tbody
    - @tasks.each do |task|
      %tr
        - table_cells("tasks").each do |cell|
          - cell.call(task)
```

In this case the ID column is only rendered if a local named `id` is passed into the partial and set to true and the Name, Start, and End columns will always be rendered. You would then call the partial like:

```
render "table" # Only renders the Name, Start & End columns
```

or

```
render "table", :id => true # Renders the ID, Name, Start, & End columns
```

Comment: Your suggestion would work if I knew about all of the possible column headers beforehand.  However, this partial is part of a rails engine (a gem) that is used by different applications created by other departments in my organization.  Also, the code I provided here is a simplification of the actual code, and having every single possible column coded in the same partial would make that partial quite bloated.

Comment: I find it confusing how the initial view could be *immediately* rendering the HAML for the ID column because that view doesn't even have a **task** variable.  The **task** variable doesn't get set until rendering the partial.  Any idea how that works?